# Will elements inserted by emplace_back always pick up the ::end() iterator?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

If I'm inserting an element at the back of a container (e.g. with `emplace_back()`, is the new element always guaranteed to be at the previous ::end() position?

Compare the following example: Here this works because I can pass the iterator to the newly inserted entity object which relies on it in turn to output "Hello World" to the console. I want to know if this is guaranteed to always work for every container.

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, std::vector and consorts are already out because of reallocation after insert. But I'm still wondering if it is true for all [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) that are iterator-preserving after insert.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:62,endLineNumber:30,positionColumn:62,positionLineNumber:30,selectionStartColumn:62,selectionStartLineNumber:30,startColumn:62,startLineNumber:30),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Clist%3E%0A%0Astruct+entity%0A%7B%0A++++entity(std::function%3Cvoid()%3E+fn)%0A++++++++:+++fn_(+fn+)%0A++++%7B+%7D%0A%0A++++auto+print()%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++auto+operator()()+-%3E+void+%7B%0A++++++++fn_()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++std::function%3Cvoid()%3E+fn_%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ausing+list_t+%3D+std::list%3Centity%3E%3B%0Ausing+iterator_t+%3D+list_t::iterator%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++list_t+mylist%3B%0A%0A++++mylist.emplace_back(%5Bit+%3D+mylist.end()%5D%7B+it-%3Eprint()%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto%26+item+:+mylist)+%7B%0A++++++++item()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:24,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:24,positionLineNumber:8,selectionStartColumn:24,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:24,startLineNumber:8),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <list>

struct entity
{
    entity(std::function<void()> fn)
        :   fn_( fn )
    { }

    auto print()
    {
        printf("Hello World!");
    }

    auto operator()() -> void {
        fn_();
    }

    std::function<void()> fn_;
};

using list_t = std::list<entity>;
using iterator_t = list_t::iterator;

int main()
{
    list_t mylist;

    mylist.emplace_back([it = mylist.end()]{ it->print(); });

    for (auto& item : mylist) {
        item();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's guaranteed **not** to work for every container.

Comment: It won't work for `std::vector` when reallocation occurs.

Comment: @Jarod42 Right! Maybe I should ask differently: Are iterators valid for every container that is iterator preserving after insert according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container?

Comment: "is the new element always guaranteed to be at the previous ::end() position?" Always? I would say never, at least I did not see such guarantee anywhere.

Comment: *"every containers that.."*. So you talk only about `list`/`forward_list`?

Comment: `mylist.end()` might be a sentinel (still the same value), so deferencing it would be UB.

Comment: [`std::list::end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end)  _"...This element acts as a placeholder; attempting to access it results in undefined behavior...."_

Comment: @RichardCritten However I'm accessing it only _after_ insertion when it possibly is not a placeholder anymore.

Comment: It is very dangerous way to deduce guarantee from behavior of particular implementation. I do not think `std::list` ever guarantee such behavior, so you see one of the consequences of UB and try to deduce rules from it, duh.

Comment: This code crashes on my machine.  The object is not created at the iterator location being captured in the lambda.  Calling `print` on a wild pointer is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: You are still access the iterator returned by `std::list::end()` which is defined to be UB.  That it appears to work (for you) is one of the possible undefined behaviours.

Comment: "when it possibly is not a placeholder anymore" and which documentation says that?

Comment: Is there a reason for this question, or are you just curious?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, I was going with this solution in production code which seemed to work flawlessy (for std::list). Then I started to doubt it...

Comment: OK, well, don't do that!

Comment: Add `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to compiler flags and [see](https://godbolt.org/z/8hdEx5eM4) what happens.

Answer (score 0):

In your shown code the lambda will capture the end iterator at the time the lambda is instantiated. Since the end iterator does not point towards a valid node you are not allowed to dereference it. it is important to understand, that your lambda has already captured the end iterator by value and this iterator will **never** update by itself. this holds for every container in the std library, i guess it will even hold for every custom container in the wild.

you dereference the end iterator when calling the lambda and by doing this you are in undefined behaviour land. your program is illformed and no output is guaranteed.

Comment: I know that it will capture by value and always stay the same. I was just curious if the end iterator will be the one where the next element is allocated. After thinking about it I find that quite strange because std::list will malloc the new node. But it's a bidirectional iterator and not a random access iterator, I guess that's why it works (in my case). Thanks anyway!